# Liferay: [SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:630] Reject process action

Tags: java, liferay-6

I'm trying to upload file in Liferay, and I tired went I upload "large" file size (more than 2MB). With log

> [SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:630] Reject process action

```
<%@ include file="/init.jsp"%>
<portlet:actionURL var="intergrateURL" name="intergrate" />
<aui:form method="post" action="<%=intergrateURL.toString() %>" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <aui:input name="messagContent1" />
     <aui:input name="messagContent2" />
     <aui:input name="uploadFileHere" type="file"/>
     <aui:button value="submit" type="submit"/>
</aui:form>
```

Portlet Action:

```
public class IntergratePortlet extends MVCPortlet {

public void intergrate(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) {

    UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = PortalUtil
            .getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);

    String messageContent1 = uploadPortletRequest.getFullFileName("uploadFileHere");
    String messageContent2 = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,
            "messagContent2");

    InputStream fileInputStream = null;
    byte[] fileByteArray; 

    MessageContentBean messageContentBean = new MessageContentBean();

    messageContentBean.setMessageContent1(messageContent1);
    messageContentBean.setMessageContent2(messageContent2);

    try {
        fileInputStream = uploadPortletRequest.getFileAsStream("uploadFileHere");
        fileByteArray = ReceiveMessage.convertInputStreamToByteArray(fileInputStream);
        messageContentBean.setFileMessage(fileByteArray);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SendJmsMessage sendJmsMessage = new SendJmsMessage();
    sendJmsMessage.doSendMessage("103.74.121.22", messageContentBean);
    // sendJmsMessage.doSendMessage("127.0.0.1", messageContentBean);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options :

**Option 1 :**

Add below to your portlet.xml to disable the csrf protection by liferay :

```
    <init-param>
        <name>check-auth-token</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </init-param>
```

**Option 2 :**

Change ${liferay_installed_dir}/portal-ext.properties to add below :

**auth.token.ignore.portlets=${form}_WAR_${portlet}**

Would suggest you to use "**Option 1**" , for details you may refer to [this post](http://junjun-java.blogspot.sg/2017/06/liferay-6-reject-process-action-for-url.html).

For how to disable CSRF per action please search liferay official document/wiki with key words:

- "portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist"
- "portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist.action"